# Understanding of MACRO in C

Tags: c

I have used many MACRO's in my project. But recently I have seen a macro which I couldn't able to understand.

```
#include "stdio.h"

  #define   ELV_CODE        
 #define    MAN_CODE        
 #define    CHANGE_DAT      
 #define    DAT_MAN_CODE    

 #define MY_FUN(type, memclass) memclass type

typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef uint8 ReturnType;

MY_FUN(ReturnType, CHANGE_DAT) Occ_Fun(unsigned int MyEvent)
{
    uint8 Return_Val = 1;
     printf("Hello World\n");
     return Return_Val;
}

int main()
{
  char str[20];

  strcpy(str, "Hello, Word!");
  Occ_Fun((unsigned int)16);
  return 0;
}
```

In above Code there is a MACRO for MY_FUN. The MACRO Should be either

> MY_FUN(type, memclass) memclass

or

> MY_FUN(type, memclass)  type

But what #define MY_FUN(type, memclass) memclass type mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply have to remember that there are *simple* macros and *function-like* macros. The former is something like:

```
#define TWIPS_PER_INCH 1440
```

while the latter is of the form:

```
#define THREE_X_PLUS_Y(x,y) (x) * 3 + (y)
```

and involves passing "parameters" to the macro to be used in the body, so that your code:

```
int z = THREE_X_PLUS_Y (10, var2);
```

becomes:

```
int z = 10 * 3 + var2;
```

---

With the macro definitions you have there, this:

```
#define CHANGE_DAT
#define MY_FUN(type, memclass) memclass type
MY_FUN(ReturnType, CHANGE_DAT) Occ_Fun(unsigned int MyEvent)
```

will be transformed into:

```
ReturnType Occ_Fun(unsigned int MyEvent)
```

(because `CHANGE_DAT` is an empty simple macro).

---

This sort of trick is used in a header like `used_by_all.h`:

```
EXTERN int xyzzy;
```

where `EXTERN` is defined as nothing (or undefined) in the code where you want to define the variable: it becomes:

```
int xyzzy;
```

In code where you just want to declare the variable (declare that it exists but not actually create it), you make sure that you have:

```
#define EXTERN extern
```

before you include the header file. That means all those translation unit (C source files) will have the line:

```
extern int xyzzy;
```

in them.

Comment: It is also important to use parentheses when using macros (e.g.' #define THREE_X_PLUS_Y(x, y) (x) * 3 + (y)'. Otherwise 'THREE_X_PLUS_Y(a+b, c)' turns into 'a+b*3+c'.

Comment: @Shay, made that change. I wasn't overly concerned since I was simply showing how the substitution parameters worked. To be complete, I'd also warn about using parameters more than once (and then passing `x++`) but that's probably overkill (since my example _doesn't_ do that) and I'm sure it's covered elsewhere. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

A macro with parameters will use this parameters during macro expansion which is basically a simple text substitution:

```
#define MY_FUN(type, memclass) memclass type
```

will simply replace the macro with its arguments:

```
My_FUN(first, second)
```

will get expanded to

```
second first
```

no black magic.